# Alert does not appear on page load in .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple .cshtml page and My problem is when I run this page alert is not shown. Here is the  .cshtml page code:

```
            @{
                Layout = null;
            }

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                <title>ChartDataJSON</title>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert('hello');
                </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <div id="chart1" ></div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Also I have a controller class through which this view is generated. The lines written in that class are:

```
            public class jqPlotController : Controller
                {
                    //
                    // GET: /jqPlot/

                    public ActionResult Index()
                    {
                        return View();
                    }

                    public ActionResult ChartDataJSON()
                    {
                        var chartData = new List<jqplotModel>();

                        var point1 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(1), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(3) };
                        var point2 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(2), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(4) };
                        var point3 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(6), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(6) };
                        var point4 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(106).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(4), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(2) };
                        chartData.Add(point1);
                        chartData.Add(point2);
                        chartData.Add(point3);
                        chartData.Add(point4);

                        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
```

Is this due to the “return” keyword in the controller class which stops alert pop up from appearing on the web page.

Has anybody faced this type of issue before. Can somebody help me in figuring out the problem?

Edit:
The view is added with respect to ChartDataJSON method of controller class.

Update: I have made following changes in view and the controller class is as mentioned above.

```
            @{
                Layout = null;
            }

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                <title>ChartDataJSON</title>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $.ajax("/jqPlot/ChartDataJSON")
               .done(function (data) {
                   // do something with the data. 
                   alert("success");
               })
            </script>

            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <div id="chart1" ></div>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: It will show alert when page loaded first time. As you shown in controller that you are returning Json on AJAX call alert will not show.

Comment: what is the url you are trying to open?

Comment: The url is /jqPlot/ChartDataJSON

Comment: The action you are trying to run will not return a ViewResult (the html markup) it will only return JSON. To return the Html you must write this return View([name of view], [model])

Comment: In your case you will have only chartData serialized in JSON in your response. In your flow .cshtml file will not be used at all.

Answer (score 0):

When returning JSON result you will not render out any Views (HTML markup). To return the HTML markup you must write this

```
return View("name of cshtml file without .cshtml");
```

where [name of view] is the name of the cshtml file you were referring to (without the .cshtml extension), and the model can be the data you want to use in the cshtml file.

To retrieve the data using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can use this command as a example

```
$.ajax( "/jqPlot/ChartDataJSON" )
  .done(function(data) {
     // do something with the data. 
     alert( "success" );
  })
```

Update:
To load the view you have to call an action that returns and renders the view. Lets say your view is named Index.cshtml and its full path is "Views/jqPlotController/Index.cshtml 
Then all you have to do is call the URL of the action, http://[nameofdomain]/Index .
Then the view should be loaded and the javascript function trigger and call the action ChartDataJSON, which will return the JSON result and in this case the alert is triggered if the call to the action is successfull.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39742/discussion-between-user1254053-and-stian-standahl)